# Can access Google api in browser but unauthorized from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, youtube-api

If I put the following url in the browser:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=algebra&key={My_API_KEY}

it works fine, however, when I try and use angular to get this, I get an unauthorized error:

```
$http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=algebra&key={MY_API_KEY}");
```

Also, my key is set to "Any referer allowed".

Why does this work one way, but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

I had an httpInterceptor setup to inject in an authorization header for my requests to an api I had previously set up. This was causing the request to be undefined. I changed the interceptor to set authorization to undefined and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

When you open it in browser you access file directly when you try to do that from your code you have to take in account CORS and cross-domain calls

what you have to do is to use `jsonp`

```
$http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?
part=snippet&q=algebra&key={MY_API_KEY}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK");
```